# Hillegass: Cocoa Prog 3rd Ed: Ch. 33 on OpenGL: Where's the Matrix?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsmatrix

I'm using XCode 3.1.4, on OSX 10.5, targeting same. In Ch. 33 we're asked to drag an NSOpenGLView and an NSSlider onto the IB library, and then do Layout -> Embed Objects in ->
Matrix.  Except the Matrix option is always disabled.

What do I have to do to enable the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out -- just select the slider, not both items.  Once you know that an NSMatrix is for replicating a widget, that makes sense.

Comment: In particular, a matrix is a matrix of cells, which means you can only make one from a control. A slider is a control, but an OpenGL view is not. Also, all the cells have be of the same kind, so you can only make a matrix from a single control; even if you had two controls, you couldn't make a single matrix from them.